# Upscaling data in Cuda

Tags: cuda

Implementing a matrix to be upscaled horizontally and vertically.
For example, 3 channel data is upscaled 4 times as shown below.

[image]

[image]

My cuda code is working for that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "ResizeAreaKernel.h"
#define DEBUG
using namespace std;
__global__ void ResizeAreaKernel(float *input, float *output, int upscale, int w, int h, int c, int total)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;//there are w*h number of threads
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    for (int i = tid; i < total; i += stride){
       int rowadd= ((int)(i/w)*c*w*upscale*upscale)-((int)(i/w)*w*c*upscale);//(j*3*5*4*4) - (j*5*3*4)
       for(int y = 0; y < upscale; y++){
          int s=i*c*upscale+rowadd;
          int e=s+upscale*c;
          for(int x = s; x < e; x=x+c){
             for(int c_ = 0; c_ < c; c_++){
                output[x+c_+y*c*w*upscale] = input[i*c+c_];
             } 
          }       
       }
    }
    return;
}


int ResizeAreaInference(float *input, float *output, int upscale, int w, int h, int c)
{  
    int N = w*h*c;    
    const int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 256;
    const int NUMBLOCKS = (int)((float)(N+THREADS_PER_BLOCK-1)/THREADS_PER_BLOCK); 
    ResizeAreaKernel<<<NUMBLOCKS, THREADS_PER_BLOCK>>>(input, output, upscale, w, h, c, N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}

#ifdef DEBUG
void printdata(float *ptr, int size, const char* name, int stride)
{
   ofstream myfile;
   myfile.open (name);
   for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
      if(i % stride == 0 && i!=0)
         myfile << "\n";
      myfile << *(ptr+i) << ",";


   }
   myfile.close();
   return;
}

int main(void)
{
   int w = 4;
   int h = 3;
   int c = 3;
   int upscale = 4;
   float *in, *out;

  // Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
  cudaMallocManaged(&in, h*w*c*sizeof(float));
  cudaMallocManaged(&out, 10*h*upscale*w*upscale*c*sizeof(float));

  // initialize x and y arrays on the host
  for (int i = 0; i < h*w*c; i++) {
    in[i] = rand() % 100;
  }
  printdata(in, w*h*c, "input.txt",w*c);
  ResizeAreaInference(in, out, upscale, w, h, c);

  // Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
  printdata(out, w*upscale*h*upscale*c, "output.txt", w*upscale*c);

  // Free memory
  cudaFree(in);
  cudaFree(out);

  return 0;
}

#endif
```

But I need to take more space in memory for output buffer (now is 10 times)

```
cudaMallocManaged(&out, 10*h*upscale*w*upscale*c*sizeof(float));
```

I need `h*upscale*w*upscale*c*sizeof(float)` this much of memory for output, but if I don't take extra space, I have

```
Bus error (core dumped)
```

What could be problem?

Comment: Did you test whether most basic CUDA C++ code works? I don't have CUDA C++, but I suggest first applying CPU-only simulation of the code to check for possible bugs.
P.S. why is there `#include "ResizeAreaKernel.h"`? It doesn't seem right.

Comment: Y `ResizeAreaKernel.h` is not necessary.

Comment: Is it because of Unified Memory? I suspect. I changed to normal `cudaMalloc,cudaMemcpy`, I don't have this issue.

Comment: It might be. Unified Memory isn't perfectly supported on older generations of Nvidia GPUs (pre Pascal, i.e., pre geforce 1070/1080). Debug mode might also be contributing to the problem.

Comment: 5 seconds with cuda-memcheck shows a number of out of bounds read errors. As with your last version of this question -- the indexing in your kernel is broken

Comment: @ALX23z i used TX2. TX2 is pascal.

Comment: @talonmies Now kernel is fixed.

Comment: @batuman: So what is your question then?

Comment: Previously can't run the code. Now I have correct outputs. So assumed kernel is correct. I just started coding for cuda. So there are out of bounds error, how can I fix those?

Comment: @talonmies thanks for the suggestion. I found that I have used too many threads.

Comment: I found that I used more threads than required.

Comment: That claim makes no sense. You have a guard statement which restricts any thread from running beyond the first `total` entries in the input/output. And you set total to `w*h*c` . So the number of threads you run should not matter, and no out of bounds reads should be able to occur. Unless, of course, the indexing calculations within the kernel are wrong

Comment: With the kernel fixed - does it work now? It might be the case that Unified Memory model reacts badly to out-bound edits, worse than common out-of bound modifications.

Comment: @ALX23z the attached code works well. Just that I deployed more threads. I just need (w x h) number of threads for my kernel. I deployed (w x h x c), that was the issue for the attached code.

Comment: @talonmies according to my kernel, i just need `w*h` number of threads only. Now I changed to `N=w*h`, no more such issue.

Comment: @talonmies now it works for any number of `c`and any number of `w and h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is, quite frankly, getting a bit tedious watching you post new versions of this code, pronouncing that they now either work or don't work when all of them have had the same or related indexing issues within the kernel code ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57320721/681865) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57321228/681865))

So to put you out of your misery, here is how I would do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template<int c>
__global__ void ResizeAreaKernel(float *input, float *output, int upscale, int w, int h)
{
    int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int tidy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    if ( (tidx < h) && (tidy < w) ) {
        int lda_in = w * c;
        int lda_out = w * c * upscale;

        int pid = tidx * lda_in + (c * tidy);

        float pixel[c];
#pragma unroll
        for(int i=0; i<c; i++)
            pixel[i] = input[pid+i];

        for(int r1=0; r1<upscale; r1++) {
            for(int r2=0; r2<upscale; r2++) {
                int oid = (upscale * tidx + r1) * lda_out + (upscale * c * tidy) + (r2 * c);
#pragma unroll
                for(int i=0; i<c; i++)
                    output[oid+i] = pixel[i];

            }
        }
    }
}


int ResizeAreaInference(float *input, float *output, int upscale, int w, int h, int c)
{  
    dim3 bdim(16,16);
    int gx = ((h + bdim.x - 1) / bdim.x); 
    int gy = ((w + bdim.y - 1) / bdim.y); 
    dim3 gdim(gx,gy);

    switch(c) {

        case 1:
            ResizeAreaKernel<1><<<gdim, bdim>>>(input, output, upscale, w, h);
            break;

        case 3:
            ResizeAreaKernel<3><<<gdim, bdim>>>(input, output, upscale, w, h);
            break;

        case 4:
            ResizeAreaKernel<4><<<gdim, bdim>>>(input, output, upscale, w, h);
            break;
    }

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}

void printdata(float *ptr, int size, const char* name, int stride)
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open (name);
    for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
        if(i % stride == 0 && i!=0)
            myfile << "\n";
        myfile << *(ptr+i) << ",";
    }
    myfile.close();
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int w = 41;
    int h = 31;
    int c = 3;
    int upscale = 4;
    float *in, *out;

    // Allocate Unified Memory  accessible from CPU or GPU
    cudaMallocManaged(&in, h*w*c*sizeof(float));
    cudaMallocManaged(&out, h*upscale*w*upscale*c*sizeof(float));

    // initialize x and y arrays on the host
    for (int i = 0; i < h*w; i++) {
        float val = i+1.0f; 
        for(int j=0; j<c; j++) {
            in[i*c+j] = val;
        }
    }
    printdata(in, w*h*c, "input.txt", w*c);
    ResizeAreaInference(in, out, upscale, w, h, c);

    printdata(out, w*upscale*h*upscale*c, "output.txt", w*upscale*c);

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(in);
    cudaFree(out);

    return 0;
}
```

[Caveat -- code very lightly tested, use at own risk ]

This code takes input like this (for the 41 x 31, three channel case):

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 -o batu4 batu4.cu

$ cuda-memcheck ./batu4
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

[image]

and emits this:

[image]

A couple of points:

1. It makes much more sense to use a two dimensional grid for this sort of kernel. The code is simpler and easier to understand, and performance will also probably be better
2. The channel count is likely only ever going to be 1,3 or 4 floats per pixel, so it makes sense to make that a constant, rather than a kernel argument. The compiler can (and does) do a lot of optimizations which will improve performance when this can be declared as a constant. C++ templates are a useful way of doing this
3. Your choice of using random numbers for pixel values made debugging much more difficult than it needed to be. By setting each channel of each input value to a known value, it becomes possible to look at the output of the kernel and instantly understand how the indexing scheme  must be failing.
4. Similarly, it would have been extremely easy and informative to run your code with just one thread to look at the output to see that the indexing was incorrect, and then with `cuda-memcheck` to see how the out-of-bounds reads and writes were occurring.
5. The solution to your problem only requires a pen and paper and some simple integer arithmetic. Once you understand the mathematics of the problem, writing the code becomes self-evident. Try it next time.

Comment: Thanks @talonmies. i scarified three points deducted to learn new things :). But worth it. I am new to work on CUDA, so thanks for help.